# Removing background of previous frames from matlab gif

Tags: matlab

I have the following Matlab code for a gif, but can't seem to get it to not show every single frame (i.e. once a frame appears, it does not disappear for the duration of the gif). I want each frame to not have contents from the previous frame.

```matlab
dt = 0.05
filename = 'test.gif'; 
figure;
for t = 0:pi/16:2*pi
    line([1,2],[3+0.5*sin(t),3+0.5*sin(t)], 'linewidth',5)
    line([1,2],[1-0.5*sin(t),1-0.5*sin(t)], 'linewidth',5)
    xlim([0 3]) 
    ylim([0 4])
    set(gca,'XTickLabel',[], 'YTickLabel', [], 'ZTickLabel', [], 'visible', 'off')
    set(gcf,'color','w');
    im = frame2im(getframe(1));
    [imind,cm] = rgb2ind(im,256);

    if t == 0;
        imwrite(imind,cm,filename,'gif', 'Loopcount',inf,'DelayTime',dt);
    else
        imwrite(imind,cm,filename,'gif','WriteMode','append','DelayTime',dt);

    end
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`clf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clf.html) to clear the contents of the figure before drawing the next frame.

You should put it right at the beginning of the loop:

```matlab
dt = 0.05
filename = 'test.gif'; 
figure;
for t = 0:pi/16:2*pi
    clf; % clears the figure to have an empty frame
    line([1,2],[3+0.5*sin(t),3+0.5*sin(t)], 'linewidth',5)
    line([1,2],[1-0.5*sin(t),1-0.5*sin(t)], 'linewidth',5)
    xlim([0 3]) 
    ylim([0 4])

    set(gca,'XTickLabel',[], 'YTickLabel', [], 'ZTickLabel', [], 'visible', 'off')
    set(gcf,'color','w');
    im = frame2im(getframe(1));
    [imind,cm] = rgb2ind(im,256);

    if t == 0;
        imwrite(imind,cm,filename,'gif', 'Loopcount',inf,'DelayTime',dt);
    else
        imwrite(imind,cm,filename,'gif','WriteMode','append','DelayTime',dt);

    end
end
```